# Android Create Intent inside of IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intentservice

I'm very new to Android and I've been banging my head against the wall on what I believe is probably a trivial problem - I've looked through tutorials and other StackOverflow questions but to no avail.

I'm trying to create an Intent inside of an IntentService but constantly get NullPointerException on the line marker ERROR below (in the sendNotification method).

I've variously tried:

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);

Intent intent = new Intent(SQLHealthService.this, TestActivity.class);

to no avail, always yielding a null pointer exception when trying to create the Intent.

```
    public class SQLHealthService extends IntentService {
.
.
.
    public SQLHealthService(String url) {
        super("SQLHealth Service");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.wsURL = "http://demo9138157.mockable.io/";
        serverList = new ArrayList<Server>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "SQLHealthService invoked");
    getServers();
    }

    List<Server> getServers() {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(wsURL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                .
                                    .
                                    .
                    sendNotification(notify);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not create json object");
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            // System.out.println(response);
        }
         });

         return serverList;
      }

    private void sendNotification(int notify) {
    try {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class); <-- ERROR
    intent.putExtra(Constants.FORCE_RELOAD, true);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("SQL Server issues detected")
    .setContentText(notify + " SQL Servers with issues have been detected")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.database)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.erase_database, "View", contentIntent)
    .addAction(0, "Remind", contentIntent)
    .build();

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    mgr.notify(0, mNotification);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

EDIT: For clarity I should mention what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'm attempting to use the AlarmManager to have the app 'wake up' every 10 minutes, make a call to a REST web service and then if certain conditions are met send a notification.

SQLHealthService is called from

```
public class SQLHealthAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      // onReceive must be very quick and not block, so it just fires up a Service
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "SQLHealthAlarmReceiver invoked, starting SQLHealthService");
          context.startService(new Intent(context, SQLHealthService.class));
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IntentService](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) is not designed to wait for a response. As soon as you go back from `onHandleIntent`, if there is no intent in the queue any more the service is killed (look at the documentation for the reasoning behind this). So when you get to `sendNotification`, no context exist.

Comment: When you say 'go back from onHandleIntent' can you clarify - I mean, onHandleIntent calls getServers which calls sendNotification

Comment: no, it's not. onHandleIntent calls getServers, which registers a callback named AsyncHttpResponseHandler. AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess is called later on which in turn calls sendNotification. So sendNotification is called in a callback and not a direct call.

Comment: Ah - I see your point - by any chance can you tell me a more 'correct' way to do this?  I'm updating the question with what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: You need to use a Service instead of an IntentService. IntentService is a simple extension to a Service (I have linked the source code of it to my answer). Look at the source code and it should give you some hint to start.

Comment: Ended up setting the web service call as a regular HttpClient instead of an AsynchHttpClient